# Please let me know feasibility using Excel and VBA programming and suggest solution approach

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

We have following requirement to be done via excel and VBA programming. Please check and let me know if it feasible to do so and if not what way would be best to do it.

There would be excel spreadsheet say excel 2007/2010 with 2 tabs.
1st tab contains normal excel data
In 2nd tab user can enter a particular value and then click on a button in same tab. Is it possibly to have a button in excel tab and can it raise events like windows/web applications?
Now if button can be kept in excel and it can raise button click event then on such an event we need to create xml files. Is it possible to create xml files adhering to schema using excel &/or VBA programming

Comment: Answer: yes and yes. Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to activate the developer tab (from backstage go to Options and check the visibility of this tab) to get access to normal windows controls, like buttons and drop-down lists etc. You can easily place those in Excel sheets and write event handlers: the controls support the full range of events, including OnClick, OnMouseEnter etc...

You can write custom text files directly from VBA, but you can't validate those. The usual way to do so is just to concatenate small XML blocks into a bigger file, so XML output is more like a normal text output. But it works fine and as long as you do not need to perform something really complicated it is also ok.

**EDIT:** You can easily add references to custom COM objects (.dll or .ocx) and use them directly in your VBA code. One very helpful suggestion (see the comment below) is to use the MS XML library.

To add a reference just open the code editor (Alt + F11) and then go to Options -> References. Most of the references you need will be already in the list and you just have to check them, but you can also add your own custom libraries by clicking on Browse.

Comment: you can also add a reference to the MS XML parser (MSXML6.dll) which you might find useful working with xml data

Comment: Thanks Alaudo & Chris. Jean, I have not tried anything so far and I would like to know if you have created a xml file validated against schema using VBA since the answer by Alaudo & Chris seems to indicate against what I understand from your comment.